# Laravel 5 - проблема с контроллером ресурсов

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Есть роут:
`Route::resource('/customer/projects/', 'ProjectsController');`
Есть контроллер со всеми методами, код не привожу, так как там стандартный набор методов, + пару своих. Суть проблемы в том, что методы:
Index, Create, Store работают, а остальные нет.
Если обратиться по ссылке: http://localhost:8000/customer/projects - index сработает
Если обратиться по ссылке: http://localhost:8000/customer/projects/create - create работает
Но, по ссылкам:
http://localhost:8000/customer/projects/id/,
http://localhost:8000/customer/projects/1/edit/,
методы show и store не вызываются.
Возникает ошибка: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:
Никак не соображу в чем проблема.
Зато, если сделать так, все работает: 
 
`Route::resource('customer/projects/', 'ProjectController');
Route::get('customer/projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@show');
Route::get('customer/projects/{id}/edit', 'ProjectController@edit');
Route::delete('customer/projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@destroy');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на консольную команду:

```
artisan route:list
```

она дает возможность посмотреть весь список действующих путей.

Я создал тестовый контролер ProjectsController и выставил в роутере

```
Route::resource('customer/projects/', 'ProjectsController');
```

Я догадывался в чем проблема, но решил всё же убедиться используя route:list

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects                           | index                | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index                          | web                |
|        | POST      | customer/projects                           | store                | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store                          | web                |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects/create                    | create               | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create                         | web                |
|        | PUT|PATCH | customer/projects/{}                        | update               | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@update                         | web                |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects/{}                        | show                 | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@show                           | web                |
|        | DELETE    | customer/projects/{}                        | destroy              | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@destroy                        | web                |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects/{}/edit                   | edit                 | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@edit                           | web                |
```

Если убрать слэш в конце роутера

```
Route::resource('customer/projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

Появляется переменная projects в конце пути:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects                           | projects.index       | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index                          | web                |
|        | POST      | customer/projects                           | projects.store       | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store                          | web                |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects/create                    | projects.create      | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create                         | web                |
|        | PUT|PATCH | customer/projects/{project}                 | projects.update      | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@update                         | web                |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects/{project}                 | projects.show        | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@show                           | web                |
|        | DELETE    | customer/projects/{project}                 | projects.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@destroy                        | web                |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customer/projects/{project}/edit            | projects.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@edit                           | web                |
```

Скорее всего слэш виноват в вашей проблеме.